# Using S3 partial keys in AWS SDK with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm reading: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getBucketCors

I have a partial key ex: "/myfolder/myinnerfolder/"

However there are actually many objects (files) inside of myinnerfolder.

I believe that I can call something like this:

```
$result = $client->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key'    => $key
        ));
        return $result;
```

If I have the full key. How can I call something like the above but have it return all of the objects and or their names to me? In Python you can simply request by the front of a key but I don't see an option to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you need to list objects with prefix option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [listObjects() method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listObjects) with the `'Prefix'` parameter.

```
$result = $client->listObjects(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Prefix' => 'myfolder/myinnerfolder/',
));
$objects = $result['Contents'];
```

To make this even easier, especially if you have more than 1000 objects with that prefix (which would normally require multiple requests), you can use the [Iterators feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-iterators.html) of the SDK.

```
$objects = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Prefix' => 'myfolder/myinnerfolder/',
));
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    echo $object['Name'];
}
```

Comment: Oh awesome thank you. Wait so each object it is the key or the object itself?

Comment: For example what if I have a jpg, and a png in "/myfolder/myinnerfolder/" is there any way to tell them apart from echo $object?

Comment: ListObjects returns information about your objects, including their names. See the [API docs for ListObjects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listObjects) and check the "Returns" section for details.